# Can you have a macro to cast Charge if in bear, a cast sequence if in cat?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

This is for the [stampede talent](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=78893) where you can ravage without being stealthed after a cat form feral charge. I wanted one button to do `Feral Charge` if in bear form, and the cast sequence of `Feral Charge(Cat Form);Ravage` if in cat form.

```
#showtooltip
/cast [nostance:1/3,nostealth] !Bear Form
/cast [stance:1]Feral Charge(Bear Form);[stance:3] Feral Charge(Cat Form)
/stopmacro[nocombat]
/startattack
```

This is what I have so far. I tried:

```
/cast [stance:1]Feral Charge(Bear Form)
/castsequence [stance:3]Feral Charge(Cat Form);[stance:3]Ravage
```

and

```
#showtooltip
/castsequence [stance:1]Feral Charge(Bear Form);[stance:3]Feral Charge(BearForm);[stance:3]Ravage
```

The [stampede talent](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=78893) is causing all kinds of special case issues for my macro plans.

Comment: `/castsequence Feral Charge(Cat Form),Ravage` does not work, it says you are not in stealth form! So... even after working out the syntax issues which caused my solutions to fail, there appears to be a bug preventing the macro from working

Comment: You have to keep spamming it, there's a slight delay between your feral charge and when you get the buff allowing you to ravage out of stealth.

Answer (score 3):

The other issue is a bug - detailed in this [thread](http://us.battle.net/wow/en-us/forum/topic/981899073#1)

If you don't have Ravage on a button somewhere on your bars, even if that button isn't shown, Ravage will not function in a macro when not stealthed.

This macro does lots for me:

```
#showtooltip
/cast [nostance:1/3] !Bear Form
/cast [stance:1] Feral Charge(Bear Form)
/castsequence [stance:3, target=mouseover,exists,harm,nodead] [stance:3] reset=10 Feral Charge(Cat Form), Ravage, Ravage
/stopmacro [nocombat][stealth]
/startattack
```

It's on the upper left bar at the bottom bound to Alt-2.

2nd Ravage is there in case the first fails because of lag or out of range.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an *idea*:

```
/cast [stance:1]Feral Charge(Bear Form)
/stopmacro[stance:1]
/castsequence Feral Charge(Cat Form);Ravage
```

Lemmie know if that works the way you want, because I'm going to get that talent rather soon with my new Druid. These animal forms are wreaking havoc on my action bars.

Comment: +1 helpful answer. yeah the action bars are very druid unfriendly. This probably would work, except for 2 issues. One of which is my original question attempts, the other is slightly outside of the scope of this question I think. Adding comments on the question.